# How do I match elements of an array to a given string using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I have this Java code method which compares the elements of an array of strings with a string variable. This method requires two argument: an argument of type string `haystack` and an array of strings `needles`. If the length of the needles array is greater than 5, it outputs an error message to the console. Otherwise it tries to match the elements of `haystack` with `needles` using regex. My code returns this:

```
abc: 0
def: 0
cal: 1
ghi: 0
c: 0
```

What changes do I need to make so that it matches both `cal` and `c`. That is the matching works for multiple character elements as well as well as single character elements?

```
public class Needles {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] needles = new String[]{"abc", "def", "cal", "ghi", "c"};
    findNeedles("cal'", needles);

  }

  public static void findNeedles(String haystack, String[]
    needles) {
    if (needles.length > 5) {
      System.err.println("Too many words!");
    } else {
      int[] countArray = new int[needles.length];
      String[] words = haystack.split("[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
      //String[] words = haystack.split("", 0);
      for (int i = 0; i < needles.length; i++) {
        

        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
          if (words[j].compareTo(needles[i]) == 0) {
            countArray[i]++;
          }
        }
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < needles.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(needles[j] + ": " + countArray[j]);
      }
      

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contains method directly on the haystack. In your first for loop use something like:

```
if(haystack.contains(needles[i])
     doSomething
```

You dont really need regex here.

Comment: Really? let me try this. Thanks!